# Как по выбору из списка ComboBox запускать методы?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "None"; //проверка
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Sort")
        {
            if (One.check != 0)
            {
                One.BubbleSort();
            }
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "MinMax")
        {             
                One.MinMax();
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Average")
        {
            if (One.check != 0)
            {
                One.Ave();
            }
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "PairUnpair")
        {
            if (One.check != 0)
            {
                One.ParOrNot();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: checkBox1_... возможно неправильный метод использую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У ComboBox есть событие SelectedIndexChanged. Его нужно запрограммировать, как и checkBox1_CheckedChanged в примере.

**UPD** Что, вот так, и не заработало?

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Text = "None"; //проверка
    if (comboBox1.Text == "MinMax") One.MinMax();
    else if (One.check != 0) {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Sort") One.BubbleSort();
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Average") One.Ave();
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "PairUnpair") One.ParOrNot();
        }
    }
```

Comment: так и сделал но не при выборе из списка проверочный textBox1 не сработал

Comment: к сожалению, нет(

Comment: Поясните толком, что вам нужно сделать. Что не заработало? Не забыли назначить комбобоксу обработчик события, а не просто вставить код в программу?

Comment: А да, вот он. Забыл назначить обработчик события)